# Spring Transaction Propagation from NOT_SUPPORTED to REQUIRES_NEW

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm working on refactoring a module with an initial method annotated with `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)` and this method invokes another method that has the annotation `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`.

My question is, since the initial method is not creating a new transaction, the invoked method will create a new transaction?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the invoked method will create and run in a new transaction.

REQUIRES_NEW will always create a new transaction irrespective of transactional mode of caller method (even if caller already created a transaction).